# optimising resources loaded on website

Tags: css, image, optimization

My question, is that if i have a folder on my website with lots of images in it, but only reference one image in that folder on my page, will the entire folder be stored in memory or on the page and be counted as utilised resources? I'm quite convince that it can't be the case. But just want to be sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Only the referenced resources in the mark-up or css will be loaded, not the entire folder.